# How to take average of one column in dataframe but for every 5 min from datetimestamp column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      Event time Event type  Ignore       Price  
0  1526076933917      kline       0       18202362   
1  1526076937493      kline       0       18202367
```

I convert the 'Event time' column to human readable format with this line:

```
df['Event time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event time'], unit='ms')
```

Now dataframe looks like this:

```
               Event time Event type  Ignore        Price  
0 2018-05-11 22:15:33.917      kline       0       18202362   
1 2018-05-11 22:15:37.493      kline       0       18202367
```

From here how do I take the average of 'Price' for every 5 min from the 'Event time' column and keep all the other columns the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.Grouper` with a `freq` of 5 minutes (`freq='5min'`):

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
Event time,Event type,Ignore,Price
1526076933917,kline,0,18202362   
1526076937493,kline,0,18202367'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data))
df['Event time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event time'], unit='ms')

df['avgPrice'] = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min', key='Event time'))['Price']
                    .transform('mean'))

print(df)
```

And you get:

```
               Event time Event type  Ignore     Price    avgPrice
0 2018-05-11 22:15:33.917      kline       0  18202362  18202364.5
1 2018-05-11 22:15:37.493      kline       0  18202367  18202364.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sacul an d@Anton vBR!